# Minecraft CanBreak on specifically colored banners

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to make an axe for my capture the flag game called "Flag Breaker" so when players enter the arena they are in adventure mode but using flag breaker they can break the flag. I've looked into can break but the with the command I have come up with under "CanDestroy" it just says MissingNo which I assume means missing number. I have tried to use block id in place of the word Banner but it still just says MissingNo. If someone could tell me the proper structure for using can break on colored banners (Red and Blue) that would be great

I am on a 1.12.2 minecraft server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to have to disappoint you, as it is not possible to only allow players to destroy a banner with a certain color. Either a player can destroy all banners, or non at all.

An alternative would be to place an entity with a colour of your preference and add it to the team who is not allowed to break it. The opposite team can kill that entity, in order to "break the flag".

EDIT

So I've been doing some testing. I've replaced `"minecraft:banner"` with `{id:"minecraft:banner"}`, but that didn't work. I've tried to omit the `minecraft:` part, but that didn't work either. I've tried with and without quotes, but no result. Lastly, I tried to make it work on dirt, like this: `CanDestroy:["minecraft:dirt"]` and that *did* work. This means that your syntax is not the problem. This appears to be a bug in the game.

Comment: ...but in 1.13 it works.

Comment: My current issue is even when i just write banner it says missingno. I'd be okay with it not being specific I have command block filters that dont let the red team capture the blue flag anyway. (i used scoreboard tags) How do i let them break all banners?

Comment: also sorry i meant CanDestroy

Comment: @CCC Could you please add the command that you used in your question? Without the command, we can't tell you what's wrong.

Comment: My command is /give @p minecraft:iron_axe 1 0 {CanDestroy:["minecraft:banner"],display:{Name:"Flag Breaker"}} also sorry i should've added that in the first place

Comment: @CCC I've edited my answer using your command!!